# Nginx unable to access files under home directory in AWS EC2

Tags: javascript, linux, nginx, amazon-ec2

I am using Nginx to serve index.html file in AWS EC2 ubuntu instance. When I have build files of the website under any folder other than home then it works file but when I have it in home folder, it doesn't work.

My config of file under /etc/nginx/sites-available/default.

This doesn't work.

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server;
        root /home/ubuntu/frontend/_work/react-frontend/react-frontend/build;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name _;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }
```

This one works. Under /var/temp there is index.html

```
server {
        listen 80 default_server;
        listen [::]:80 default_server
        root /var/temp;
        index index.html index.htm index.nginx-debian.html;
        server_name _;
        location / {
                try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html =404;
        }
```

[Under home folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DpMmb.png)

[Under var folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ovMCf.png)

Answer (score 0):

this happens because you need to describe the root location properly and check the permission of the file. also, make a root as a files group owner. for reference I attaching a review using this and I suggest changing the server name to localhost.